# MemoryError в DecisionTreeClassifier.fit()

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

Обрабатывал .csv файл для дальнейшей работы с ним.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = pd.read_csv('E:\datasets\sf-salaries\Salaries.csv', sep=',')

file = file[:40000]

file.columns.values.tolist()

file = file.drop(['Notes','Agency','Status', 'Id', 'EmployeeName'], axis=1, errors='ignore')

target = file.JobTitle

file = file.drop('JobTitle', axis=1)

feature_names = file.columns.values.tolist()

for column in feature_names:
    file[column].fillna(0, inplace=True)

data = np.array(file, dtype='float64')

def code(target):
    i = 0
    codes = {}
    data = list()

    for key in target:
        if not key in codes:
            codes[key] = i
            i += 1

    for value in target:
        data.append(codes[value])

    return np.array(data, dtype='float64')

target = code(target)

target_names = 'JobTitle'

DataSet = namedtuple('DataSet', 'target_names target DESCR data feature_names')

my_dataset = DataSet(target_names, target, '', data, feature_names)

data = my_dataset.data

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(my_dataset.data, my_dataset.target, random_state=42)

tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Правильность на обучающем наборе: {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Правильность на тестовом наборе: {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

В каждой строке находится семь числовых значений типа float64. В качестве ответов представлены числа от 0 до 1341.

В качестве  модели выбрал дерево решений из sklearn. При обрезке датасета до 39.000 всё работает(хоть и правильность на тестовой выборке крайне мала), однако при 40.000 и выше возникает MemoryError. Как с этим бороться?
Описание ошибки:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-f806560e5940> in <module>()
      1 tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
----> 2 tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
      3 print("Правильность на обучающем наборе: {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_train, y_train)))
      4 print("Правильность на тестовом наборе: {:.3f}".format(tree.score(X_test, y_test)))

c:\users\камп\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    788             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    789             check_input=check_input,
--> 790             X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
    791         return self
    792 

c:\users\камп\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    360                                            min_impurity_split)
    361 
--> 362         builder.build(self.tree_, X, y, sample_weight, X_idx_sorted)
    363 
    364         if self.n_outputs_ == 1:

sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx in sklearn.tree._tree.DepthFirstTreeBuilder.build()

sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx in sklearn.tree._tree.DepthFirstTreeBuilder.build()

sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree._add_node()

sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree._resize_c()

sklearn\tree\_utils.pyx in sklearn.tree._utils.safe_realloc()

MemoryError: could not allocate 135790592 bytes
```

Comment: 39 000 каких попугаев? Сколько весит одна строка? Когда запускаете скрипт, включите консоль и смотрите, что Вам говорит htop. Может быть у вас и правда память рвёт.

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые замечания и рекомендации...

1. Первое, что бросается в глаза - вы используете 32-битный Python. В этом случае процессу Python доступно не более 2 GiB, даже если объем свободной памяти гораздо больше.
2. Несмотря на нехватку памяти, вы используете тип даных `float64`, который занимает в 2 раза больше памяти по сравнению с `float32`.
3. Гораздо эффективнее читать только нужные столбцы и строки, нежели читать весь CSV файл в память и только потом обрезать его. Кстати при обрезании в памяти создается копия DataFrame (пусть и на короткое время, но это может приводить к `MemoryError`)
4. Вместо использования функции `code()` можно использовать тип данных `category` при чтении CSV и впоследствии передавать `sklearn` коды категорий, используя атрибут `df['col_name'].cat.codes`
5. Методам `SciKit-Learn` могут напрямую обрабатывать Pandas.DataFrame - нет нужды создавать еще одну копию данных в виде Numpy NDArray

   ---

Попробуйте так:

```
fn = r'E:\datasets\sf-salaries\Salaries.csv'

target_col = 'JobTitle'
cols2drop = ['Notes','Agency','Status', 'Id', 'EmployeeName']
cols = pd.read_csv(fn, nrows=0).columns.drop(cols2drop)
data = pd.read_csv(fn, usecols=cols, dtype={target_col:'category'}, nrows=50000).fillna(0)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(data.drop(target_col, axis=1), data[target_col].cat.codes, 
                     test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Я использовал float64, поскольку выдавало ошибку выхода за граница типа float32.

Comment: @mydiamondsdancing, можете выложить ваш CSV на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: Сомневаюсь, т.к. не пользуюсь ни одним. А чтение `data` вызывает `ValueError: fill value must be in catogories`.

Comment: @mydiamondsdancing, врядли вам смогут помочь, не имея __воспроизводимого__ примера данных. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)